# Using FineUploader, can I pre-populate the upload area with files from a specified folder?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, fine-uploader

I am using [FineUploader](http://fineuploader.com/) and have figured out how to upload images to the server.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#fine-uploader-gallery').fineUploader({
    template: 'qq-template-gallery',
    request: {
      endpoint: "./vendor/fineuploader/php-traditional-server/endpoint.php"
    },
    deleteFile: {
      enabled: true,
      endpoint: "./vendor/fineuploader/php-traditional-server/endpoint.php"
    },
    chunking: {
      enabled: true,
      concurrent: {
        enabled: true
      },
      success: {
        endpoint: "./vendor/fineuploader/php-traditional-server/endpoint.php?done"
      }
    },
    resume: {
      enabled: true
    },
    retry: {
      enableAuto: true,
      showButton: true
    },
    thumbnails: {
      placeholders: {
        waitingPath: './node_modules/fine-uploader/jquery.fine-uploader/placeholders/waiting-generic.png',
        notAvailablePath: './node_modules/fine-uploader/jquery.fine-uploader/placeholders/not_available-generic.png'
      }
    },
    validation: {
      allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png']
    }
  });
});
```

Now I would like for the images from a specified folder to appear within the upload area when the user refreshes the page or initially loads it. How can I do that?

Comment: If you are talking about "JavaScript adding files to a file upload control without explicit user action", AFAIK, you can't. It's a major security threat that has been mitagated. Imagine what this functionality could do. "Upload any file from a user client to a server without the user knowning". (it's easy to hide elements from view).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. Simply enable the ["initial files list" feature](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/session.html) and be sure your server responds to the GET request sent by Fine Uploader with the proper JSON data. For example, if you have some files server-side that you want to be represented in the initial file list, and you would like Fine Uploader to send a GET request to an endpoint at `/my/server/initialfiles`, your config would look something like this:

```
var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
   session: {
      endpoint: '/my/server/initialfiles'
   }
})
```

...and your server's response to this request will look something like this (assuming only one file is to be represented):

```
[{ "name": "foo.jpg", "uuid": "7afs-sdf8-sdaf-7asdf", "thumbnailUrl": "/my/server/foo.jpg" } ]
```

You can omit the `thumbnailUrl` property if you don't have an image to render for the file.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! Your code rocks! What is the `uuid` and where do I get that?

Comment: Each upload request includes a uuid as a qquuid parameter. You should store this alongside the file entry in your database. For files not uploaded by fine uploader that you want to represent on load, just return whatever other unique ID you've associated with the file in your DB.